# Custom ajax loader gif in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides

How can I override the default ajax loader gif in Magento 2?
I can only find answers to do this in Magento 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
magento\app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<YourTheme>\web\images\loader-1.gif
magento\app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<YourTheme>\web\images\loader-2.gif
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Had to deploy after creating the gifs, and it worked!